# Blender animation in the model

Tags: animation, three.js, 3d, blender, 3d-modelling

I want to create an animation using Blender for the model. Typically, when making an animation in Blender, the final output is a video file. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to save the animation data itself directly onto the model. In doing so, I could then use a different viewer, such as Three.JS, SwiftUI app or another compatible tool, to play the animation on the model. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can save the blender file and it will save the animation, so then anyone you share the blender file with will be able to see the animation.

Any program or website that can read Blender files (Like Unity and Sketchfab) will be able to read some of the animation as well. You can also export to FBX or gltf, which will preserve some of the animation data. However, the export process primarily preserves "skeletal animation" which is animation on "armature" objects in Blender. You can animate in other ways in Blender (like shape-keys and modifiers) but this animation may not export well to FBX or gltf or import well to other programs. So, if you are planning to use the animations you make in Blender as animations in other software, plan to animate using armatures, and do small tests to make sure your work will transfer properly.

For Three.JS specifically, the gltf file format is probably best to transfer animation data.

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to run the animation somewhere, for example in Three.JS, do I need to make some `animation.run()` or how does it work?

Comment: The way to run an animation will depend on where you are running it. In Blender, the shortcut for play and pause an animation is the SPACEBAR key. For details of the Three.JS animation system, please check the documentation:
https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Animation-system

Comment: And if I want to use animations also in my SwiftUI app, I need to use .usdz or .gltf, what is the best format to keep all in one file both textures and animation?

Comment: I know Blender can export to .gltf but the 'best' format will depend on your specific use case. It is not hard to export to multiple formats and try them all out. I encourage you to do so, not only to solve your current problem but also to increase your confidence in your ability to solve problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks. And for example about animations, is there some plug-in for “auto animate” by my armature? And how to make talking animations? Do I need to make some “holes” in my model mouth?

Comment: Yes. Look up "lip sync" for information on how to make talking animation.